# Print NSImage from base64 string

Tags: objective-c, macos, base64, nsimage

I'd like to print a base64 encoded image (passed in from canvas in a web view). How can I read/print a base64 string? Here's what I have so far:

```
- (void) printImage:(NSString *)printerName andData:(NSString *)base64img andW:(float)paperW andH:(float)paperH {
    
    NSImage *img = [base64img dataUsingEncoding:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    [printInfo setTopMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setBottomMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setLeftMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setRightMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    
    [printInfo setPaperSize:NSMakeSize(paperW, paperH)];
    [printInfo setPrinter:[NSPrinter printerWithName:printerName]];
    
    NSPrintOperation *op = [img printOperationForPrintInfo: printInfo autoRotate: YES];
    
    [op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [op setShowsProgressPanel:NO];
    [op runOperation];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has at least three errors:

```
NSImage *img = [base64img dataUsingEncoding:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

- First, the [`dataUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416696-datausingencoding?language=objc#) message asks the string to **encode** itself as data, but you want a **decode** operation, not an encode operation.
- Second, the `dataUsingEncoding:` method requires an [`NSStringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencoding?language=objc) argument, and [`NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatabase64encodingoptions/nsdatabase64encoding64characterlinelength?language=objc#) is not an `NSStringEncoding`. (It is an [`NSDataBase64EncodingOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatabase64encodingoptions?language=objc).)

  Unfortunately, because you are using Objective-C instead of Swift, the compiler doesn't reject this code. (Maybe it gives a warning though? I didn't try it.)
- Third, `dataUsingEncoding:` returns an [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata?language=objc#), not an [`NSImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage?language=objc#). I'm pretty sure the compiler emits at least a warning for this.

You need to decode the string to an `NSData` using [`initWithBase64EncodingString:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410081-initwithbase64encodedstring?language=objc), and then you need to create an `NSImage` from the `NSData` using [`initWithData:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519941-initwithdata?language=objc).

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64img
    options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
if (data == nil) {
    return;
}

NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
if (img == nil) {
    return;
}
```